# Get Mvc3 Ajax.ActionLink replaced data with Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an `@Ajax.ActionLink` that replaces his own wrapper, with another content that also has `@Ajax.ActionLink`, that returns first html content to wrapper. It's link to partial that replaces it's self and viceversa. My problem is that when i want some aditional functionaliti on click to ActionLink, my Jquery returns old partial, the one that has been click, and not the new, in firebug i clearly see my new elements, but cannot reach them, i tried, OnSuccess and OnComplete, but didnt succed! Any ideas?

Here's example:

**VIEW**

*index.cshtml*

```
<div id="box">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialOne")
</div>
```

_*PartialOne.cshtml*

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Get partial two", "getPartial2", "Home",
                new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "box",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "GET"       
                    },
                    new { @class="first"}
                )
<div id="testBox1">Hello, I am partial 1</div>
```

_*PartialTwo.cshtml*

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Get partial one", "getPartial1","Home",
                new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "box",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "GET"
                    },
                    new { @class="second"}
                )

<div id="testBox2">Hello there this is partial 2</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

*HomeController.cs*

```
public PartialViewResult getPartial1()
{
    return PartialView("_PartialOne");
}

public PartialViewResult getPartial2()
{
    return PartialView("_PartialTwo");
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#box a.first").live('click', function () {

    //how to fetch new data, that was filled with getPartial2()

    console.log($(this).parent().children());

    //this returns [a.first, div#testBox1] 
   // and I need [a.second, div#testBox2] 
});
```

*How to select returned data to let's say substring if neccesary??*

***EDIT***

*using OnComplete = "function"*

**VIEW**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Get partial two", "getPartial2", "Home",
                new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "box",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        OnComplete = "getNewData"       
                    },
                    new { @class="first"}
                )
<div id="testBox1">Hello, I am partial 1</div>
```

**JS**

```
function getNewData()
{
    console.log($(this));

    //this returns [Object] of ajax call, niether
   // $(this).parent/s(), or $(this).children() is posible

}
```

How to select children of element that called this ajax?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, can you take a look at this...

Comment: as of jQuery 1.7, .live() is deprecated. You should use .on(). http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @ZachGreen, thanks, but that doesn't resolve this question?

Comment: that is why i made it a comment and not an answer

Comment: @ZachGreen, any ideas for answer?

Comment: Try to write ajax requests manually without using ajax helper.

Comment: @EvgenyLevin, this is one of the solutions, but is there solution for helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I am not 100% what you are looking for, but I think maybe your issue is caching. If you tack a unique parameter onto the GET request, do you get the result you are looking for?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Get partial two", "getPartial2", "Home", new { aparam = DateTime.Now.Ticks },
                new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "box",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        OnComplete = "completeGetThing"       
                    },
                    new { @class="first"}
                )
<div id="testBox1">Hello, I am partial 1</div>
```

Comment: my goal is to get new elements returned by controller, with same click that triggerd the ActionLink, so i can manipulate them... before displaying.

Comment: supplying a javascript function for the OnComplete parameter will set that function to execute when the action is complete, and then you can manipulate the page however you need.